# dbatools import csv help!

Tags: sql-server, import, powershell, etl, dbatools

Is there a way I can import **csv** files with the proper data types into MSSQL table using PS dba tools?

I'm using this below command but all I get is a table and all the columns are nvarchar(max):

```
Import-DbaCsv -Path C:\user.csv -SqlInstance $server -Database $DB -AutoCreateTable
```

I know I can achieve this by SSIS but it's not the best option for me as some of the CSV structures keep changing, +/- Columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Import-DbaCsv`, refer to [the help text for the `-ColumnMap` parameter](https://docs.dbatools.io/Import-DbaCsv.html)

> By default, the bulk copy tries to automap columns...

For CSV files with variable column headers, `Import-DbaCsv` will make a best-guess at mapping what goes where (so column names and datatypes matter a lot).

Demo it for yourself.

```sql
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists foo;
create table dbo.foo (
     id int not null primary key identity
    ,foo varchar(100) 
    ,bar int 
    ,baz date
    ,bin varchar(100) 
);
```

Note the difference in columns for `foo.csv` and `foo2.csv`

```
@"
foo,bar,baz
aaa,111,1900-01-01
bbb,222,1900-02-02
ccc,333,1900-03-03
"@ | Set-Content foo.csv

@"
foo,bin,baz
ddd,444,1900-01-04
eee,555,1900-02-05
fff,666,1900-03-06
"@ | Set-Content foo2.csv

$importSpec = @{
    SqlInstance = "localhost"
    Database    = "tempdb"
    Schema      = "dbo"
    Table       = "foo"
}

Import-DbaCsv foo.csv @importSpec -Verbose
Import-DbaCsv foo2.csv @importSpec -Verbose
```

```sql
select * from tempdb.dbo.foo;
```

Note the columns are properly mapped in the database target

| id | foo | bar | baz | bin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | 111 | 1900-01-01 |  |
| 2 | bbb | 222 | 1900-02-02 |  |
| 3 | ccc | 333 | 1900-03-03 |  |
| 4 | ddd |  | 1900-01-04 | 444 |
| 5 | eee |  | 1900-02-05 | 555 |
| 6 | fff |  | 1900-03-06 | 666 |

---

Disclaimer: I wrote [v1 of the AutoMap logic](https://github.com/dataplat/dbatools/pull/5321) though it has changed since then.

Comment: Hi Peter Vandivier, thanks for your reply. I like the -column and -columnMap parameters,  these will work when an SQL table is already created, they will definitely help me in designing what im looking for.
I was looking for a solution that helps me creating the tables with proper data types.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem in your use case is that it is not possible for bulk loader to guess correctly column sizes or even data types. You see, in most ETL implementations, column types and lengths are specified well in advance. The loader can trust that the data either fits the destination, or classify it as a broken one.

The loader could not know that, say, row 501 has very long string of 1500 characters in product description, whilst all the other rows have just a few dozen of letters. If it guesses that the column is shorter, row 501 will not load correctly. If it plays it safe and makes everything `nvarchar(max)`, data fits but is inefficient and no type checks are done.

Now, the loader *could* read through the whole file and keep a count on each column max lengt and data types. Then it could create a table according to these specifications. Then it would read the whole file again, and do the insertion. This would require reading the file twice, which is inefficient and usually not needed since ETL processes rely on pre-agreed file formats. Some tools, such as SQL Server Management Studio's Import wizard do this, kind of. It reads the first 200 rows from a file and base the guess on that piece of data. And that's why I suggested the mismatching data is on row 501, far too far from the sampler component.

There are tools, such as [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) that can create table structure from a CSV file. Wether it's any good, I have no experience.

Comment: Hi vonPryz, thanks for your reply and detailed explanation. I will give the csvkit a try and get back to you.
cheers.